# How to run whole test cases sequentially in maven using testng?

Tags: java, testng

1. I want to run my whole test cases sequentially in java maven using testng.
2. How to run test suite sequentially?

Comment: There are several testing framework available in the market like Junit, TestNG, and Cactus etc. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Maven Surefire Plugin with TestNG](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html) (Using Suite XML Files)

```
<plugins>
    [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
          </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    [...]
</plugins>
```

And to know how to configure the testng.xml please follow [TestNG documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-in-xml).

Hope these information will guide you properly.